# Entity framework throwing cannot insert null value exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this code which adds restaurant to datbase

```
  public Restaurant Add(Restaurant newRestaurant)
    {
        db.Restaurants.Add(new Restaurant());
        return newRestaurant;
    }

     public int Commit()
    {
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When i call Commit i get error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Location',
>   table 'OdeToFood.dbo.Restaurants'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated

Although column Location is populated from GUI. See here

[image]

But still it throws error. Anyone idea what it can cause this issue? Location column is set to nvarchar and its non nullable.

Comment: From what you are describing and the comment below it looks as if the value you are saving is not the same as the value you are displaying in debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your not passing the `newResturant` object to EF, you're passing a `new Resturant()`

```
public Restaurant Add(Restaurant newRestaurant)
{
    db.Restaurants.Add(new Restaurant()); <--- this right here is a brand new object
    return newRestaurant;
}
```

You should be doing this

```
public Restaurant Add(Restaurant newRestaurant)
{
    db.Restaurants.Add(newRestaurant);
    return newRestaurant;
}
```